# Getting answer in static Main after calculations in other class

Tags: c#, class

I need to display sum in static Main but calculations to be done in other class. I keep getting 0. Why?

```
namespace ConsoleApp7{

    public class Perimetro_skaiciavimas
    {

        public static void Main()
        {
            {
                var kvadrato_perimetro_skaiciavimas = new kvadrato_perimetro_skaiciavimas();

                Console.WriteLine("Ivesti kvadrato krastiniu ilgius");
                Console.Write("Krastine A: ");
                kvadrato_perimetro_skaiciavimas.a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Krastine B: ");
                kvadrato_perimetro_skaiciavimas.b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine(kvadrato_perimetro_skaiciavimas.perimetras); // GIVES ME A 0 how to get SUM?
            }
        }
    }
    public class kvadrato_perimetro_skaiciavimas
    {
        public static int a, b, perimetras;

        public void skaiciavimas() {
            perimetras = a + b;     //PROBLEM AREA
        }
    } }
```

Comment: Remove `static` from  `public static int a, b, perimetras;` fields of `kvadrato_perimetro_skaiciavimas` class

Comment: modify the name of instance do not as same as class name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your modified code is below. The issue is you aren't calling the method skaiciavimas().

Your naming convention of class isnt following the C# standard. Also, if your method names are more like verbs (CalculatePerimtras) etc, that will be great.

Parsing user input can be done like TryParse or try catch exception is also recommended. Lastly, using variables like this totally violates OOP principle.

```
public class Perimetro_skaiciavimas
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        {
            var kvadrato_perimetro_skaiciavimas = new kvadrato_perimetro_skaiciavimas();

            Console.WriteLine("Ivesti kvadrato krastiniu ilgius");
            Console.Write("Krastine A: ");
            kvadrato_perimetro_skaiciavimas.a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Krastine B: ");
            kvadrato_perimetro_skaiciavimas.b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            kvadrato_perimetro_skaiciavimas.skaiciavimas();
            Console.WriteLine(kvadrato_perimetro_skaiciavimas.perimetras); 
        }
    }
}
public class kvadrato_perimetro_skaiciavimas
{
    public static int a, b, perimetras;

    public void skaiciavimas() {
        perimetras = a + b;     //PROBLEM AREA
    }
 } 
}
```

Comment: I would not have static fields either.

Comment: That worked, thanks. A clear example helped a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

In your other class you have defined the variable as static, which means the value is defined before the object is fully constructed.  Your other class should look like the following:

```
public class Calculator
{
     public float Sum(params float[] parameters) => result = parameters.Where(parameter => parameter != null).Sum(parameter => parameter);
}
```

From your entry point you can know read all of your inputs, then pass them to the `Calculator.Sum` to calculate for you by simply doing `new Calculator().Sum(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);` for instance.  You could avoid the Linq if you would like and manually iterate and sum, but up to you.

Your current code is failing because:

- Incorrectly using static (Zero is assigned because that is default value and is initialized before construction.)
- Should likely sanitize user input with `TryParse` instead of `Parse` since if it fails it will throw exception.
- You do not call your sum method either.